# Magento: Difference between loading product through collection than product model

Tags: magento, attributes

So we were trying to load a product through a collection with certain criteria, we didn't have the sku or the id so when we did the following

```
 $prodModel->getCollection()
        ->addAttributeToFilter('visibility', $visibility)
        ->addAttributeToSelect('*')
        ->addCategoryFilter($cat)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_1', $sattribute_1)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_2', $attribute_2)
        ->addAttributeToFilter('type_id', 'configurable')
        ->load()
        ->getFirstItem()
```

When doing this we got the product we wanted but for some reason it didn't have all of the attributes, even though we specified "*" for all attributes. Specifically the one we were not getting was the media gallery attribute. What we ended up doing is saying getFirstItem()->getId() then loaded the product and it worked find.

I just don't understand whey loading the product with the catalog product model would have more attributes.

Comment: I don't know the answer to your question, but I can confirm that Magento has always behaved that way.  It's been necessary to perform a `load()` on the individual product. I've never seen the `'*'` attribute selector, have you seen that in the Mage codebase, or something you're trying?

Comment: We have used it all the time, I have seen it in many peoples examples when loading collections. I could even try to load the media gallery attribute and it still wouldn't, I am assuming I would of had to do a join? But then that is why I want to know the difference between getting a product this way through a collection and just loading it

Answer (score 1):

I understand you actually asked how to get all of the attributes but I notice you also mention the media gallery attribute specifically.
There happens to be a shortcut for getting the product image's final URL.

```
(string)Mage::helper('catalog/image')->init($product, 'media_gallery');
```

Casting to a string calls `__toString` which performs the cleverness. You can also apply resizing, rotation, watermarks, etc. immediately after initialising.